Eliminating impossible branches in Coq dependent pattern matching
I'm having troubles with understanding pattern matching on dependent types. Let's say we have following code:
Variant Op := op1 | op2.

Variant Res : Op -> Set :=
| r1 : Res op1
| r2 : Res op2
| rb : forall op, Res op
.

Variant Node := n1 | n2.

Definition nops (n: Node) : Op :=
  match n with
  | n1 => op1
  | n2 => op2
  end.

Definition nedg (n: Node) (rv: Res (nops n)) : bool :=
  match n, rv with
  | n1, r1 => true
  | n1, rb _ => false
  | n2, r2 => true
  | n2, rb _ => false
  end.

As it is written, it curses about non exhaustive pattern-matching in nedg, because we do not consider n1, r2 and n2, r1 branches. Given nedg declaration, our moral right to cut them away is pretty obvious, so, the question is, what would be the most idiomatic way to convince type checker that omitted branches are actually impossible?

Welcome to the wonderfull world of dependent pattern matching. You cannot always convince the type-checker that some case are excluded, depending on how much tweaks have been included in its current revision (of the type-checker).
But you can do it by hand. By generating an absurdity for the excluded cases. Here is a possible solution:
Variant Op := op1 | op2.

Variant Res : Op -> Set :=
| r1 : Res op1
| r2 : Res op2
| rb : forall op, Res op
.

Variant Node := n1 | n2.

Definition nops (n: Node) : Op :=
  match n with
  | n1 => op1
  | n2 => op2
  end.

Definition not_op1 o :=
 match o with 
 | op1 => False
 | _ => True
 end.

Definition not_op2 o :=
 match o with 
 | op2 => False
 | _ => True
 end.

Definition nedg (n: Node) : Res (nops n) -> bool :=
  match n with
  | n1 => fun rv => match rv in Res o return not_op2 o -> bool with
    | r1   => fun _ => true
    | rb _ => fun _ => false
    | r2   => fun C => match C with end
    end I
  | n2 => fun rv => match rv in Res o return not_op1 o -> bool with
    | r2   => fun _ => true
    | rb _ => fun _ => false
    | r1   => fun C => match C with end
    end I
  end.

Goal nedg n1 r1 = true.         Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
Goal nedg n1 (rb op1) = false.  Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
Goal nedg n2 r2 = true.         Proof. reflexivity. Qed.
Goal nedg n2 (rb op2) = false.  Proof. reflexivity. Qed.

Notice that C in the first match C with end is of type not_op2 op2 which reduces to False. Also, the first I is of type not_op2 (nops n1) which reduces to True.

Damn this looks ugly... If this solution is really the only one, I'll need to rethink my formalism, I fear. I'm not seeing how this can be scaled to bigger sets of Op's and more Res constructors in reasonable manner.

Indeed, I don't see how this is essentially different from just adding the two missing cases and returning false for them, even if these "will not happen".  OTOH, what does "nedg" mean?  To me the "ugliness" here seems more to suggest that the very initial definitions do not capture all that is needed.

Well the issue is indeed that there is a constraint in the type of nedg between the first parameter n : Node and the dependent parameter o of the second parameter rv : Res o, and this constraint is o = nops n. If you remove it, the solution is much simpler.

Another approach would be to view nedg not as a function but as an inductive relation of type forall n, Res (nops n) -> bool -> Prop. But it would of course not compute.

@DominiqueLarchey-Wendling, going from function to relation for nedg, actually, could be possible in my case. I wanted to conserve computability here, but not if it means dishing out stuff like suggested.

@JulioDiEgidio - sorry, I greatly reduced my actual code to get primitive example, so in this simplified form nedg completely lost its meaning.

@DoktorDiagoras then I suggest the move to an inductive characterization of nedg. You can even drop the constraint that o = nops n which leads writing casts just so that your terms type-check and write nedg : Node -> forall o, Res o -> bool -> Prop so that there is no dependency between parameters at the typing level.

The problem with match is that it loses information about what n and rv was before the match. One way to handle this is the "convoy pattern" that sends in a proof to n=n1  (etc.) to the proof.  This proof can easily be discharged with an eq_refl .
To be able to write half-finished terms with _  holes in them, you can use the refine tactic to iteratively define your term, and finish proof obligations later.
Here is an example of one way of defining the function.


Definition nedg (n: Node) (rv: Res (nops n)) : bool.
refine (
  match n as nn return n=nn -> bool with
  | n1 => fun Hn => match rv as rr in Res o return o = nops n -> bool with
    | r1   => fun _ => true
    | rb _ => fun _ => false
    | _ => fun Hrv => _
    end eq_refl 
  | n2 => fun Hn => match rv as rr in Res o return o = nops n -> bool with
    | r2   => fun _ => true
    | rb _ => fun _ => false
    | _ => fun Hrv => _
    end eq_refl 
  end eq_refl
  ).
 
exfalso; enough (op1=op2) by congruence. now rewrite Hrv, Hn.
exfalso; enough (op1=op2) by congruence. now rewrite Hrv, Hn.
Defined.

The missing information about n and rv is added as the arguments Hn and Hrv, and is used to prove the contradiction op1=op2 in the impossible branches.  It is easy to prove by rewriting.
I agree that this is not very readable.  The problem is as I said that match loses information.  It doesn't have to be that way. For example, Agda's type checker doesn't lose this information.

But, similarly to the previous answer, how is this essentially different from just adding the two missing cases and returning false for them, even if these "will not happen"?  Indeed, how does Agda solve the problem?  (From the point of view of Coq, I'd be rather inclined to suggest that the type of rv should be more specific, a sub-type of Res, otherwise that is simply it: total functions and what that entails.)

IF you can create return (nonsensical) values of the correct type even in contradictory cases you can indeed return that value instead. However, that is not always the case, and in that case it is good to be able to use the tactic exfalso, the theorem False_ind or just the term match (E:False) with end  to convince the typechecker.  And perhaps also yourself that you didn't make an error...

Hm, "convince" the type-checker of what?  I think that is the culprit...  I'd use sub-typing, then the function can be written more sensibly.  Or, I'd simply complete the pattern matching without these (spurious, would be my contention: for the sake of understanding of course) "indirections".

One must convince the type checker that the function is complete, i.e. produces a value of the correct type for any valid input.  Usually the return type is not just a bool, but some kind of proof. Like, a function that checks if a number n is prime does not just return a bool, it returns a bool and a proof that that bool is true if and only if n is prime.

But the function is complete if it is...  You are not really addressing my objection, i.e. how and why to go about it: anyway never mind, food for thought.  I'd just kindly ask you, if possible, if you could expand a little bit on that reference to Agda: I'd be quite interested.

How about formulating these new questions into separate questions? They probably are worthy of their own place. :)

Thank you: I am sure there is a depedent-type theory question there, but I am not seeing what the problem is, I can't make sense of the code in question to begin with.  Will think about it...
